# bootstrap datatable pagination table not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

bootstrap datatable pagination  table not working what am i doing wrong?  i think there is problem with files can anyone see what am i doing wrong

Live website link is [Click here to see live](http://www.choicebusinesscollege.com.au/test-page/)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">
<script language="javaScript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"  src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script language="javaScript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/3cfcc339e89/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" class="init">

jQuery(function($) {
    $('#example').DataTable();

} );

    </script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-12">
<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered display" cellspacing="0" border="1" width="100%">

<script type="text/javascript">
/*
 jQuery(function($) {
 $('#datatable').dataTable();

     $("[data-toggle=tooltip]").tooltip();
  });
*/
</script>




<?php $i = 0; ?>



<?php foreach($data as $entry): ?>



<?php if($i==0){$count = count($entry);} ?> 

    <thead>

<tr>

<?php if($i==0):  ?> 



<?php foreach ($entry as $cell): ?>

<th><?php echo $cell; ?></th>

<?php endforeach; ?> 

</thead>
<tfoot>
                        <tr>
                        <?php foreach ($entry as $cell): ?>
                            <th><?php echo $cell; ?></th>

                            <?php endforeach; ?> 

                        </tr>
                    </tfoot>
<?php else: ?>
<?php

$keys = array_keys($entry,"");

// foreach empty key, we unset that entry
foreach ($keys as $k)
unset($entry[$k]);

?>
    <tbody>
<?php foreach ($entry as $cell): ?>

<td><?php echo $cell; ?></td>

<?php endforeach; ?>     
    <tbody>


<?php endif; ?>

</tr>





<?php $i++; ?>



<?php endforeach; ?>

</table>

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Regards
Math

Comment: Can you put a picture of the resulting table? (The link provided does not work).

Answer (score 0):

I took a close look to your code, and looks like the table is not valid, if the table is malformed the DataTable plugin will not work.

In this section of your code:

```
<?php if($i==0){$count = count($entry);} ?>
     <thead>
         <tr>
            <?php if($i==0):  ?> 
            <?php foreach ($entry as $cell): ?>
                <th><?php echo $cell; ?></th>
            <?php endforeach; ?> 
     </thead>
     <tfoot>
```

a `</tr>` is missing, so that can be producing the not valid table.

From the [DataTable.net](http://datatables.net) website.

> For DataTables to be able to enhance an HTML table, the table must be valid, well formatted HTML, with a header (thead) and a body (tbody). An optional footer (tfoot) can also be used

- A tip: is better to load all the JS after you finish loading the DOM elements, doing it so will make your page load faster and the page will load completely and if JS errors are present they will be shown afterwards.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.